# How to make the next 'for' loop continue loop from previous one through dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

If the input data is a **list**, it works properly

```
list_data = [7,10,9,20,2,5,15,6,25,2,8,17,23,9,24,45,3,22,6,20,4]
pos_1 = 0
pos_2 = 0
for i in range(len(list_data)):
    if list_data[i] >= 25:
        pos_1 = i
        break
print(f"Position1 which has value greater than equal to 25: {pos_1}")
for i in range(pos_1+1,len(list_data)):
    if list_data[i] >= 25:
        pos_2 = i
        break
print(f"Position2 which has value greater than equal to 25: {pos_2}")
```

The output (the 2nd for loop will not repeat the 1st for loop)

```
Position1 which has value greater than equal to 25: 8
Position2 which has value greater than equal to 25: 15
```

But if the data is a **dictionary** like this

```
dic_data = {1: 10, 3: 20, 6: 15, 8: 25, 11: 17, 12: 23, 14: 24, 15: 45, 17: 22, 19: 20}
index_1 = 0
for i in range(len(dic_data)):
    if(dic_data.values() >= 25):
        pos_1 = dic_data.keys()
        index_1 = i
        break
print(f"Position1 which has value greater than equal to 25: {pos_1}")

for i in range(index_1+1,len(dic_data)):
    if(dic_data.values() >= 25):
        pos_2 = dic_data.keys()
        break
print(f"Position2 which has value greater than equal to 25: {pos_2}")
```

Of course it must be an error

**How to handle with the dictionary data?** (Both of them aren't my actual code, it's just an example)

Comment: With a dict, what does represent key and value regarding your first code ? If the value is higher than 25 keep the key ?

Comment: What do you mean with "Of course it must be an error"? You haven't told us what the outcome is of the second code block. I would recommend that you print out the different conditions and functions for the dicts, so that you can see what they do. Because I don't think this code is doing what you want it to.

Comment: Sorry everyone for my unclear questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.keys()` and `.values()` represents the whole list of keys or values, you can't do anything on it regarding comparison or index. You need to iterate on dict's pairs : `items`

```
dic_data = {1: 10, 3: 20, 6: 15, 8: 25, 11: 17, 12: 23, 14: 24, 15: 45, 17: 22, 19: 20}
index_1, pos_1, pos_2 = 0, 0, 0
for idx, (k, v) in enumerate(dic_data.items()):
    if v >= 25:
        pos_1 = k
        index_1 = idx
        break
print(f"Position1 which has value greater than equal to 25: {pos_1}")

for idx, (k, v) in enumerate(list(dic_data.items())[index_1 + 1:]):
    if v >= 25:
        pos_2 = k
        break
print(f"Position2 which has value greater than equal to 25: {pos_2}")
```

```
Position1 which has value greater than equal to 25: 8
Position2 which has value greater than equal to 25: 15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iterator variable with the enumerate() function:

```
dic_data = {1: 10, 3: 20, 6: 15, 8: 25, 11: 17, 12: 23, 
            14: 24, 15: 45, 17: 22, 19: 20}

iData = enumerate(dic_data.values()) # or iter(dic_data.items()) to get keys

for i,value in iData:
    if (value >= 25):
        pos_1 = i
        break
print(f"Position1 which has value greater than equal to 25: {pos_1}")

for i,value in iData:
    if(value >= 25):
        pos_2 = i
        break
print(f"Position2 which has value greater than equal to 25: {pos_2}")
```

output:

```
Position1 which has value greater than equal to 25: 3
Position2 which has value greater than equal to 25: 7
```

*Note that you cannot access a dictionary by a positional index, so the output has limited practical use*

Comment: You are right, I originally had dic_data.keys() in there, didn't realize iter() was no longer needed when I switched it to return value indexes. I fixed the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the problem. I got rid of most of the excess code.

ps: I added a variable that displays the values of the positions (`first_ value` and `second_value`) in case you want to check the validity of the answer.

```
dic_data = {1: 10, 3: 20, 6: 15, 8: 25, 11: 17, 12: 23, 14: 24, 15: 45, 17: 22, 19: 20}

extra_list = list(dic_data.values())
for i in extra_list:
    if(i >= 25):
        pos_1 = extra_list.index(i)
        first_value = i
        break
print(f"Position1 which has value greater than equal to 25: {pos_1}.The value in that position is {first_value}")

for i in extra_list[pos_1+1:]:
    if(i >= 25):
        pos_2 = extra_list.index(i)
        second_value = i
        break
print(f"Position2 which has value greater than equal to 25: {pos_2}. The value in that position is {second_value}.")
```

I created a function that should help save time

```
def greater_equal_25(list1, pos = 0):
    '''based on your needs use the value or key methods on the dictionary and then
    create a variable that has the list of the method using the list function'''
    if pos == 0:
        for i in list1[pos:]:
            if (i >= 25):
                posx = extra_list.index(i)
                second_value = i
                break
    else:
        for i in list1[pos+1:]:
            if (i >= 25):
                posx= extra_list.index(i)
                second_value = i
                break
    return posx
```